# Dagger 2.15: Appcomponent - was unable to process this interface

Tags: android, dagger-2

I cannot build my app with the following error:

```
 Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin
        debug/AppComponent.java:7: error: [ComponentProcessor:MiscError] dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this interface because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
public abstract interface AppComponent {
            ^
```

I'm using dagger 2.15 and got all of it's dependencies included:

```
    implementation deps.dagger.runtime
    implementation deps.dagger.android
    implementation deps.dagger.android_support
    kapt deps.dagger.android_support_compiler
    kapt deps.dagger.compiler
```

Code of `AppComponent.kt`

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidInjectionModule::class,
        AppModule::class,
        MainActivityModule::class]
)
interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder
        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: App)
}
```

Code of `AppModule.kt`:

```
@Module(includes = [ViewModelModule::class])
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplication(app: App): Context = app

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofitService(): RetrofitService {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://dog.ceo/api/")
            .client(createClient())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(LiveDataCallAdapterFactory())
            .build()
            .create(RetrofitService::class.java)
    }


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDb(app: Application): CacheDb {
        return Room
            .databaseBuilder(app, CacheDb::class.java, "cache.db")
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideUserDao(db: CacheDb): UserDao {
        return db.dogImagesDao()
    }

    private fun createClient(): OkHttpClient {
        val logger = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger { message -> Timber.tag("OkHttp").d(message) }

        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor(logger)
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build()
    }
}
```

Code of `MainActivityModule.kt`

```
@Suppress("unused")
@Module
abstract class MainActivityModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FragmentBuildersModule::class])
    abstract fun contributeMainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```

Code of `FragmentBuildersModule.kt`

```
@Suppress("unused")
@Module
abstract class FragmentBuildersModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeUserFragment(): UserFragment
}
```

I always run into this limited errors with Dagger. Tried to debug the task but doesn't give anymore information. Hopefully anyone else can hint me at something.

One last thing. I'm also using the `gradle wrapper 4.7` and `Android Studio 3.1.2`

UPDATE:

```
ViewModelModule.kt

@Suppress("unused")
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(UserViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindUserViewModel(userViewModel: UserViewModel): ViewModel

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}
```

Comment: Please check the gradle log for more errors, further up.

Comment: Cannot find your ViewModelModule. Please post it's code

Comment: `fun provideApplication(app: App): Context = app` should be `fun provideApplication(app: Application): Context = app`

Comment: I just changed the name for this post. Correct Application class is given.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak there is just nothing useful in the whole log except for this error

Comment: I believe what epic panda said would be the solution, so your log should show something along the lines _App cannot be provided without..._

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just doesn't say anything in the gradle console except for the task and the singel error reason stated on top of my post. I'm kinda clueless. Any ideas on how to get more info? Removing functions like provideApp doesn't change anything

Comment: Hi @SjaakRusma, did you figure out? My code is exactly as yours and had the same problem

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same code copied from Google sample GitHub and experienced the same problem. The way I solved it, as it turns out, is to clear all *other* errors in your program, especially those related to the imported modules. So I had problem with my Room database part of the code and had build-time errors. Initially I thought it's unrelated to the `AppComponent` error. But after I cleared them, everything was fine. It kind of makes sense, an unsuccessfully built module is a dependency that cannot be `resolved`. And probably the `compilation errors` in the error message meant errors in general.

Hope this will help you